# How do I configure Eclipse to run your tests automatically?

Tags: eclipse, junit, continuous-integration

I read this article: Configure your IDE to run your tests automatically
http://eclipse.dzone.com/videos/configure-your-ide-run-your

It's pretty easy to configure Eclipse IDE to run an Ant target every time a file is saved.
MyProject -> Right-click : Properties -> Builders -> New -> Ant Builder

The problem is that the builder has to rebuild the jar on every save, which is very long. The JUnit tests run using the .classes in the jar.

We already have JUnit configurations (EclipseIde .launch files which contains the whole classpath to run the tests). I wish I could create a builder that wraps those JUnit launch files. This would have the benefit of running the tests against Eclipse .classes (faster than rebuilding the jar). Also the test results are displayed in the JUnit view.

Has anybody manage to do that?

Comment: just curious: what's the major differences between the 3 solutions posted below? are any of them markedly better/worse than another?

Comment: @Jason - CT-Eclipse is eclipse specific. Infinitest is open source and being actively developed. JUnit max is also eclipse specific but costs money. It is endorsed by Kent Beck though which may make it prefered by some. I have heard many developers rave about Infinitest though so I would recommend to try it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [CT-Eclipse](http://ct-eclipse.tigris.org/), a continuous testing plugin for Eclipse.

From the plugin page:

> With CT-Eclipse enabled, as you edit your code, Eclipse runs your tests quietly in the background, and notifies you if any of them fail or cause errors.

Comment: Does anyone know if CT-Eclipse can work in newer versions of Eclipse than 3.1 mentioned here: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/continuoustesting/?  The latest message posted to the mailing list (https://lists.csail.mit.edu/pipermail/continuous-testing-plugin-discuss/2009-April/000157.html) suggests moving to JUnit Max, which is not supported any more.

Comment: JUnit Max is revived.  CT-Eclipse doesn't appear to have been touched since 2007.

Comment: The project page shows no activity on this project in 6 years at this point.  Probably best to look elsewhere.  The JUnit Max page shows a $100/yr subscription?!?  Perhaps Infinitest (http://infinitest.github.com/)...

Answer (score 37):

I recently started using [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) and it seems to somehow "know" which parts of the code affect which test cases. So when you change some code, it automatically re-runs the tests which are likely to break. If the test fails, it marks an error at the spot where it failed, the same way Eclipse would mark a coding error like calling a non-existent method or whatever. And it all happens in the background without you having to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JUnit Max](http://www.junitmax.com/junitmax/subscribe.html) it is an eclipse plug in that will run all you tests every time you save. But it will do it without interrupting your work flow. The results are shown in the left corner of Eclipse and you can always go back to the last successful testrun. The plugin runs the tests that are most likely to fail first so that you get a response for your last saving as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.junitloop.org/index.php/JUnitLoop is another one like this (haven't tried it yet myself)