# Eclipse : Running tests when you're thinking

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tdd

I read this Kent Benk [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/KentBeck/status/307271340891725825) : 
"don't wait. run the tests while you're thinking."

I am looking for some kind of plugin that allows me too do this in the eclipse IDE. For exemple, if i am away from keyboard or looking for documentation in my browser, the plugin could detect that i am not working on eclipse and will automatically launch my test.

Is there any tool like this ?

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are asking for but [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) runs the tests every time a relevant file changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [CT-Eclipse](http://ct-eclipse.tigris.org/) , a continuous testing plugin for Eclipse. But again only runs when a file has been modified and not based off user idle time.

From:
[How do I configure Eclipse to run your tests automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247174/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-run-your-tests-automatically)