# How can I execute tests automatically

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, coding-style, tdd

In eclipse, I create the test and always have to run it manually. Can eclipse run the tests when I save my class? This will save so much time.

Comment: This is a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247174/how-do-i-configure-eclipse-to-run-your-tests-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Infinitest plugin](http://infinitest.github.com/user_guide.html), which has been designed precisely to be able to do this.